# 'Gaining' instead of 'gain' in "while gain nothing for themselves at all"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> Individuals sacrifice their own benefits for others while **gain** nothing for themselves at all.

In this sentence which I composed myself, I feel **gain** should be changed to **gaining**, but I cannot explain why, so what's the correct form? why?

Comment: what is the source of this quote. You should let us know where this quote comes from

Comment: @JamesK No source , I composed it myself.

Comment: Have you tried looking up any grammar references or anything? There's a lot aimed at learners out there.

Comment: @SamBC I've already read some , but cannot find a related one

Comment: Please see [this post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4796#4796) re standard punctuation/spacing in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjunction while is used with the continuous tense of verbs:

> Don't use your phone while you are eating dinner.

When the context is clear, the subject and auxiliary verb are usually omitted:

> Don't use your phone while eating dinner.

Since the verb is used in the continuous form, it must be the present participle (not a gerund, though they have the same ending). So in your example it should be "... while gaining ...".  Implicitly it means "while individuals are gaining nothing..."